# autocomplete searches work, but not gets selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input text boxes are created dynamically via jquery. Autocomplete works well. But when I select an item its value is not rendered properly, May I know where am I missing here ?

Jquery

```
$(function() {
  var projects =  [
    {
        "label": "ajax",
        "value": "1003",
        "desc": "foriegn"
    },
    {
        "label": "jquery",
        "value": "1000",
        "desc": "dd"
    },


    {
        "label": "wordpress theme",
        "value": "1000",
        "desc": "h"
    },
    {
        "label": "xml",
        "value": "1000",
        "desc": "j"
    } ]; 

$("#addButton");
var counter = 13;

$("#addButton").click(function() {
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    var roleInput = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Role',
        name: 'Role' + counter,
        id: 'project-description' + counter
    });

    var searchInput = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'search',
        name: 'search' + counter,
        id: 'project' + counter
    });

    var hidd = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'searchhid' + counter,
        id: 'project-id' + counter
    });


    newTextBoxDiv.append(roleInput).append(searchInput).append(hidd);
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    $("#project" + counter).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project" + counter).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project" + counter).val(ui.item.label);
            $("#project-id" + counter).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-description" + counter).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-icon" + counter).attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon);
            return false;
        }
    })


    counter++;
});





});
```

`
Html is below

```
<div id="project-label"></div>

<input id="project" />
<input type="hidden" id="project-id" />

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="project-description"></p>


 <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="form-inline control-group">

 </div>
</div>
 <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton' />
```

Please tell me what am I missing in this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a JavaScript error.  Your `select` event from the autocomplete looks for `$("#project-icon" + counter)`, but I don't see that element being rendered anywhere.  Also, when trying to set the `src` attribute of that element, you reference `ui.item.icon`, but your array of values doesn't contain that property.

Comment: Thats is not stopping the autocomplete. I have checked it in my setup after removing -icon..

Comment: Oh, I see that problem now too.  After you create a new row of textboxes, you increment the value of `counter`.  That's a problem when you hit the `select` event because it's using the current value of `counter` to look for the elements on the page.  If you look for your IDs using `(counter - 1)`, it'll work, but only for the most recent row added.  Any previous rows will not work.

Comment: In your `select` event.  You're looking up HTML elements by appending the value of `counter` to their IDs.  The problem is that by the time you hit that, the value of `counter` has already been incremented, so the IDs you're looking for don't actually exist.  If you use `counter - 1`, however, they will.  Again, this will only work for the most recently added row.